# onOptionsMenuClosed() executed when the 'back' key pressed immediately after the menus were displayed. BUT

Tags: android

From the onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu) method, I stopped the thread when I was about to display the menus because background thread, which consumes lots of processng time, makes displaying and clicking one of the menus(not the menu button) nearly impossible. After the thread stops, displaying and clicking menus(not the menu button) becomes much more manageable. The problem occurred when 'back' key was pressed immediately after the menus were displayed. I need to restart the thread after when the user hits 'back' key.  When I incorporated the public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) method, the 'back' key pressed immediately after the menus were displayed did execute the void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) method. However, when I displayed the submenus from one of the menus and then hit the 'back' key, the void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) method did not get execute. I really appreciated if someone can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

it's not called because, it's only called for main menu not sub menu .. so you may think of adding some flags inside `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and inside `onBackPressed`
such as:

```java
boolean isSubMenuItemPressed;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.subMenuItem: //the item that contains the submenu 
      isSubMenuItemPressed = true;
      break;
  }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (isSubMenuItemPressed) { // do what you want 
    isSubMenuItemPressed = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time and answering the question. I will test the code you provided.

Comment: I just realized that, without testing the code, it will not work because when I do display one of the submenus from one of the menus and then hit the 'back' key, the onOptionsItemSelected() method will not be executed since I am not selecting any submenu but simply hitting the 'back' key. Furthermore, during the time when the menu button is pushed, because the focus is not in Activity class(well, in my case, it is MapActivity) anymore, I do not think the onBackPressed() method will work. I did test that scenario by having the boolean in the onPrepareOptionsMenu and check in  onBackPressed().

Comment: I am sorry that now I know why your answer was in that way. I did not click one of the submenu but displayed the submenu from one of the menus and then hit the back key.

Comment: I really don't understand ... may you rephrase your problem so that others be able to help.

Comment: When I displayed the submenus by clicking one of the main menus(without clicking one of the submenus) and then hit the 'back' key immediately, the void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) method did not get execute. I really appreciated if someone can answer this question.